# Using getter and setters vs defining properties in javascript

Tags: javascript

Other than coding style is there any advantages/disadvantages to either:

```
Circle.prototype = { radius : 10};
Object.defineProperty(Circle.prototype, 'circumference', {
     get: function() { return 2*Math.PI*this.radius; }
});
```

vs

```
Circle.prototype = {
  radius : 10,
  get circumference() { return 2*Math.PI*this.radius; }
}
```

Comment: Well the second one requires a somewhat less-commonly-available new language feature. Also, `.defineProperty()` has implicit defaults for property enumerability and mutability that I *think* are different from what you get via the new syntax.

Comment: There's an interesting paragraph on MDN's [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) documentation (above "Deleting Properties" heading). However, this only eludes to one being syntactical sugar over the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In property definition, JavaScript handles it via the internal method `DefineOwnProperty`, where assignment is handled by the internal method `Put`. In short, the second one checks whether or not a property is read-only and if yes, leads to rejection.
This can have consequences when using read-only properties, which prevent assignment, but **not** definition.

If you want to create a new property it is better use definition. If you want to change the value of a property, you can use assignment.

Take a look [here](http://www.2ality.com/2012/08/property-definition-assignment.html) for more, very interesting article.

EDIT: In fact, `defineProperty` is used for reasons such as defining read only properties and other reasons about the behavior of the property defined.
Take a look here for [more](http://designpepper.com/blog/drips/creating-unwritable-properties-with-object-defineproperty) too.

Comment: If you're going to post a link (and it's great you cited the source), please provide a synopsis in your answer first and foremost and supplement that answer with an off-site link. If that web page were to go down and someone visits days, months, years from now, this post would be useless.

Comment: Links to interesting material are great, but key points should be copied directly into answers here.

Comment: Ok, please do not downvote further, I am going to update the answer.

Comment: Answer is updated. If it is still incomplete, tell me to update further please.